# What happens once all questions are asked?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Excuse me if I am not asking this question in a philosophical manner but I will try and do my best.

The true question is what if there are no more questions to be asked in the world, would it be the end of humanities progression and if so what would be the worst thing out of it?

Comment: If "now" always refers to something that will immediately become "not now" isn't asking "what's going on right now?" always a new question?

Comment: At least one question will be left : "Why there are no more questions ?"

Comment: I suspect the more interesting thing to come out of this problem might be an idea of what a question is. It seems to me we should know that before we can evaluate their possible infinitude.

Comment: It's just as well you excused yourself in advance otherwise your question may have been unanswerable.

Comment: There would still be a lot of progress, until all those questions that are asked have been answered, or have been found to be unanswerable.

Comment: The universe ends and a new level of universe with harder questions starts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would certainly have earthshattering implications for mathematics.  One of the deeply rooted concepts within mathematics is the idea of the natural numbers (0, 1, 2, 3...).  If we were to assign numbers to each question, we would see that there's always a next question as long as there's at least a mapping from natural numbers to questions.

A trivial mapping would be "What is the most interesting feature of the number X" where X is a natural number.

If we ran out of questions, that would suggest that something fell apart in the mathematics of natural numbers, because natural numbers  should always be able to yield one more question.  That would be quite earthshattering... and most likely spawn its own questions.

Now there are other ways we could run out of questions, but they do need to be addressed on a case by case basis.  For example, if we run out of questions because we ran out of energy in the universe with which to ask them, that calls for a very different sort of contingency plan.

Comment: Your answer reminded me of "[The Last Question](http://multivax.com/last_question.html)" by Isaac Asimov.

Comment: What a simple and elegant way to show that running out of questions is impossible (barring extenuating circumstances as you mentioned last). My thought here is to suggest that every answer always reveals a new question simply because the nature of an answer is that it brings new information. Such information is then naturally prone to further inquiry because it is only recently known (and probably not fully).

Comment: @etipaced I think I generally agree with you.  My experience is that new answers always bring new questions, making your answer far more satisfying and rich than my thin mathematical proof.  Proving your answer, however, can be more difficult than one might like.  Math is good for proving =)

Comment: @CortAmmon I agree that proving what I said is most likely not possible, except through maybe an induction-based approach. But then, I'm often less concerned with "proving" anything and find myself more interested in understanding. Thanks for your feedback :-)